# XPath: Get text given condition in another DIV

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get text from a structure like this:

```
...
  <div class="a">
    <div class="a">
      <div class="a">
        <div class="inner">
          <a>
            <div class="a">...</div>
            <div class="a">&gt;</div>
            <div class="important class">Some interisting text</div>
            <div class="a">...</div>
          </a>
          <a>
            <div class="a">
              <button class="criterion A">...</button>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="a">
      <div class="a">
        <div class="inner">
          <a>
            <div class="a">...</div>
            <div class="a"/>
            <div class="important class">Some interisting text</div>
            <div class="a">...</div>
          </a>
          <a>
            <div class="a">
              <button class="criterion B">...</button>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

...
```

What I want is:
get the path to text from div with class="important class" that matches the criterium where `button` has a `class="B"` attribute.

As I am using selenium, I tried something like the following to retrieve a list of XPaths:

```
list_xpath = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="importante class" and .//button[@class="cirterion B"]]')
```

But it returns an empty list.
To retrieve the text, I would do later:

```
for path in list_xpath:
   print(path.text)
```

What is the proper way to get these text given a criterion that is in another branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this XPath:

```
//a[.//button[@class="cirterion B"]]/preceding-sibling::a//div[@class="importante class"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `text()` value `Some interisting text` by using the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//div[a/div/@class='important class' and a/div/button/@class='criterion B']/a/div[@class='important class']/text()
```

In a whole Python expression this would be:

```
list_xpath = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[a/div/@class='important class' and a/div/button/@class='criterion B']/a/div[@class='important class']/text()")
```